# Static framework with -"ObjC"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, linker

My project has already import several third party frameworks, and many of the requires "-ObjC" optimisation in Building Settings -> Linking -> Other linker flags tab.

Currently, I am trying to add another static framework (OSMap SDK), and the optimisation causes "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress", referenced from:
    -[OSTerrain getDataLoadedForEasting:northing:] in OSMap(OSTerrain.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapTiledLayerView", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in OSMap(RMMapView.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMarker", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in OSMap(RMMapOverlayView.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMOpenStreetMapSource", referenced from
    objc-class-ref in OSMap(RMMapView.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMQuadTree", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in OSMap(RMMapView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am sure that I added QuartzCore.framework and other frameworks that specified on Git.
And there's no .m file in the framework as far as I can see.

Is there a way to use a static framework while still keep the optimisation functionality under other linker flags?

**EDIT:**

1. libbz.dylib helps to eliminate the first error.
2. Right now the other four error are still exists. My guess is they should be in route-me's library, and somehow is missing. And if I import route-me's library, although this can eliminate the undefined symbol's error, it will generate more new errors of duplicate symbols.

Comment: Why not? If you have issues with your configuration, please add more details...

Comment: @Macmade Already added. :)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the missing symbols suggests that you need to link with libbzip2 and something from github called "route-me".

If you have those, you may not have them for the correct architecture.  You tagged your question iOS, but the errors are about an i386 build, perhaps you're targeting the simulator without libraries that support it.

Comment: The libbz2.dylib does eliminate the first error. However, when I try to import route-me, the RMMapTiledLayerView one and the RMQuadTree still persists. I also tried to user mapBox to replace route-me, since  it has the two missing files. Although this eliminates the two last errors, it also generate a new one which is "ld: 167 duplicate symbols for architecture i386". I guess the library is already imported, just not found?

Comment: Show one of the duplicate symbol errors as reported in the Log Navigator.  It should tell where it's finding the multiple symbols.

Comment: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RMProjection._planetBounds in:
    /Users/Yigexu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OSTileSourceDemo-drnclwpsfccilgeiebpfivmzutuo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMapBox.a(RMProjection.o)
    /Users/Yigexu/Desktop/NEW 4/ios-sdk-demo-tilesources-master/StaticFrameworks/OSMap.framework/OSMap(RMProjection.o)

Comment: So, it's saying that you're linking two copies of RMProjection…one from the OSMap framework and another from a static library called libMapBox.a.  I can't tell you which is correct but both at the same time is a problem.